# PHP MYSQL Data fetching issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am facing some problem with fetching data from SQL.

When I use the below statement, it is working fine

```
$sql = 'SELECT `Name`, `Des`, `Url`, `about`, `date` FROM `data` where name = \'facebook\''; 
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
```

When I use the same using a parameter name, I am facing some problem, the code I used is

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$sql = 'SELECT `Name`, `Des`, `Url`, `about`, `date` FROM `data` where name = \'$name''; 
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
```

I also tried by concatenating name like `\'facebook\'`

```
$name1 = "\'".$name . " \'";  but it is also not working .
```

Comment: try `name = $name` instead

Answer (score 3):

use `Double quotes` so you won't need any escaping of single quotes.

```
$sql = "SELECT  Name, Des, Url, about, date
        FROM    data 
        where   name = '$name'";
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Use Mysqli instead of Mysql.

Solution for your query :

```
$name = $_GET['name']; 
$sql = "SELECT Name, Des, Url, about, date FROM data where name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
```